# How to make a program to make an object appear and disappear by entering and exiting a trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a code to make an object appear when I enter a trigger object and disappear when exit the trigger object.

```
GameObject GhostApparition;
    // Use this for initialization
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) ;
        {
            //????
        }
    }
```

I want the object to appear when I enter a trigger object and disappear when I exit the object. Also the actual mesh should disappear too.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you know how to set GameObjects to be active or not? You already seem to have a suitable member to do this to. So where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could activate/deactivate the game object, like this:

```
gameObjext.SetActive(true); //or false
```

By activate/deactivate all attached components will be enabled/disabled as well, [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the state of a gameObject with

```
 gameObject.SetActive(true);
 gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

You just have to call it in your TriggerEnter and TriggerExit. I don't know if you want to make your "ghostapparition" inactive, but then it is:

```
GhostApparition.SetActive(true);
GhostApparition.SetActive(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, simply do it:

```
GameObject GhostApparition;
    // Use this for initialization
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player") ;
        {
             GhostApparition.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player") ;
        {
             GhostApparition.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

But be aware when you doing it with GameObjects which contains behaviors. If you deactivate it, then activating again, it'll run void Start again and reset your variables. Sometimes you not gonna want it.

So I suggest, in these times, to you just deactivate the GameObject [MeshRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshRenderer.html) Component.

Answer (score 0):

```
….monobehavior:

public GameObject object;

void Start()
{
    object.SetActive(false);
    object2.SetActive(false);
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        {
           object.SetActive(true);
           object2.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}

/// void OnTriggerStay and 'object2' are extras (for if u want a keycode to show an additional text)
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (object.activeInHierarchy && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
    {
        object.SetActive(false);
        object2.SetActive(true);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    object.SetActive(false);
    object2.SetActive(false);
}
...
```